# SQL Server 2014 - what is the most efficient way to move data from one table to another across databases same instance

Tags: sql-server, select, insert

I've found various opinions on this one, including a reference to an article that indicates that 'select into' operators can run in parallel from 2014+ and may or may not be more efficient than 'insert' as a result.

My use case is moving data from one table to another identical table across databases, same instance, 2014. The inserts will be 5-10M rows-ish, and I don't care about logging just efficiency.  I need a general recommendation, not a case-by-case analysis.

I realize that there are other factors (row length, etc) that might affect the answer, but I'm looking for the best place to start.  I can always try other methods if necessary.

So what's the most efficient way to load a table in one database from an identical table in another?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: with 5-10M rows, this sounds like a case of premature optimization.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) package that performs BULK operations.  Although 5M rows isn't significant in our current world.

Since "it depends" you'll have to help us understand what you're trying to save.  INSERT INTO is nice only in that it is self contained and "easy."   If this is a one time deal you might do it this way and stop thinking about it.

If however you're going to be shoveling 10M records daily - you might consider a scheduled SSIS script.  There is overhead to maintaining the script but it is generally faster.  If you are reloading data for testing purposes (reset to baseline) then the SSIS package is a good way to go.

You might also look at this article: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/99367/insert-into-table-select-from-table-vs-bulk-insert

Comment: thanks ripvlan.  My requirement is actually to write a stored procedure that accepts a table name and performs the data move.  If there's a way to create a package that accepts a table name, then I'd be stoked, as that would be my choice too.  I found a post from 2009 by Phil Brammer where someone asked if it were possible to write an SSIS package and pass it a table name as a variable, and he responded that it was a pretty bad idea.  Do you happen to know if that's changed?

Comment: A variable table name for copying data sounds like a bad idea to me.  I would suggest that you give a higher view of what your business problem is rather than focusing on how to do some specific thing.  I think it is somewhat likely that what you are trying to do would be handled much better in a completely different way.

Comment: As a general security problem - having a script that copy and blow away anything is typically not a good idea.  Of the (lets say 50) tables - are all of them eligible for this service?   While it may be possible to write that script - it would be ugly.  I use SSIS to import data (daily) received from a foreign source.  But I know exactly where that data is going and why.

Comment: Another thing that occurred to me last night - you are copying data to another database - which I presume means "another server" aka across the network.  You want to test this out !!  SSIS may win from performance perspective.  As @btberry says - understand your business needs.  Writing a general purpose procedure when you only need to deal with "2" tables will cause you problems in the future having to support an over engineered solution.

Comment: And finally --- is this a job for SQL Server?  Or a python/C# program?  Sometimes moving up a layer and writing "business layer logic" is a better place to go.  One person on my team wrote a C# program that contains business logic to export data, checks options, receives schedule notification etc - but then calls an SSIS script (embedded code) to do the BULK export work.  And there were several objects in the SSIS script that the C# program could control.  Separation of Concerns.  C# code rarely changes, SSIS changes only when schema changes.